# Google BigQuery SQL, selecting a range of records from a large dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am querying the GDELT 2.0 database and am tried to export the entire query but it is too big. I did a limit for 10000 and got those and I now want to get the next 10000 records and so on until I collect the entire query. This is the original command

`SELECT * FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.eventmentions] WHERE MentionIdentifier LIKE '%bitcoin%'`

I tried doing what was explained in this link: http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_limit.php

However it does not go through I'm getting an EOF error and putting in a semicolon doesn't fix it. If you know how to do this please help.

Comment: please clarify what exactly client, code you use that does not work! so we can help without guessing what you did! Ideally you should show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why are you linking to a MySQL page? This is BigQuery. Do you simply want to download the results of that query to your machine via the console, or are you using a client?